# eval in if statement design view

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, eval, repeater

I have a repeater showing product stocks. I want show if no stock "**Out of stock**". If present show stock amount and unit.

I tried the following ways:

```
<%#Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AMOUNT")) == 0 ? "Out of stock" : %><%#Eval("AMOUNT") %> <%#Eval("UNIT") %>
```

and

```
<% if ( Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AMOUNT")) == 0) { %>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='Out of stock'></asp:Label>
<%} else { %>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AMOUNT") %>'></asp:Label>
<% } %>
```

I am getting this error in this method: 
***System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.***

Maybe there is a simple solution but I can't find. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `if` condition obviously doesn't support data binding, hence `InvalidOperationException` occurs:

```
<% if ( Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AMOUNT")) == 0) { ... } %>
```

Since the `if` condition has two blocks of markup (with `else` condition), you can use two `asp:PlaceHolder` controls as replacement with different visibility condition (one equals to zero and other is greater than zero):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="AmountPlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("AMOUNT") == 0 %>'>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='Out of stock'></asp:Label>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="AmountPlaceHolder2" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("AMOUNT") > 0 %>'>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AMOUNT") %>'></asp:Label>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Or use strongly-typed [`RepeaterItem.ItemType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_RepeaterItem_ItemType) property instead of `Eval`:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="AmountPlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Item.Amount == 0 %>'>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='Out of stock'></asp:Label>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="AmountPlaceHolder2" runat="server" Visible='<%# Item.Amount > 0 %>'>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Amount %>'></asp:Label>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```